# LinkedList - Type in C - Accessing Functions

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I'm currently implementing a **LinkedList** in C out of didactic reasons. 
I am almost finished, but am now struggling because *it does not quite do what its intended to do*.

Long story short, the output is not what I expect from my code - and now I'm a little exhausted from circling around this in my brain.

Here is the whole implementation:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/********** GLOBALS *******************************/
#define DEBUG 0

/********** STRUCT AND TYPES DEFINTIONS ***********/
/* a node with key, data and reference to next node*/
typedef struct Node {
    int key;
    char string[1024];
    struct Node *next;  // pointer to next node
} Node;

/* the actual linked list: ref to first and last Node, size attribute */
typedef struct LinkedList {
    struct Node *first;
    struct Node *last;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

/********** FUNCTION HEADERS **********************/
LinkedList init_list();
void insert_end(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]);
void insert_beginning(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]);
int remove_end(LinkedList *list);
int remove_beginning(LinkedList *list);
int print_list(LinkedList *list);
void free_list(LinkedList *list);
char * get_string(LinkedList *list, int key);

/*********** FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ***************/
/* init_list Returns an appropriately (for an empty list) initialized struct List*/
LinkedList init_list() {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    LinkedList list;

    list.first = NULL;
    list.last = NULL;
    list.size = 0;

    return list;
}

/* Given a List, a key and a string adds a Node containing this
information at the end of the list*/
void insert_end(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]) {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    list->size++;                    // increment size of list

    // intialize the new Node
    Node* newN = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newN->key = key;
    strcpy(newN->string, string);
    newN->next = NULL;

    Node* oldLast = list->last;      // get the old last
    oldLast->next = newN;          // make new Node the next Node for oldlast
    list->last = newN;              // set the new last  in the list

    printf("new Node at end: %d %s %p \n", newN->key, newN->string, newN->next);

}

/* Given a List, a key and a string adds a Node, containing
this information at the beginning of the list */
void insert_beginning(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]) {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    list->size++;                    // increment size of list
    Node* oldFirst = list->first;    //get the old first node

    // intialize the new Node
    Node* newN = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newN->key = key;
    strcpy(newN->string,string);
    newN->next = oldFirst;

    list->first = newN;              // set the new first

    //special case: if list size == 1, then this new one is also the last one
    if(list->size == 1)
        list->last = newN;

    printf("new Node at beginning: '%d' '%s' '%p' \n", newN->key, newN->string, newN->next);

}

/* Removes the first Node from the list*/
int remove_beginning(LinkedList *list) {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    if(list->size <= 0)
       return -1;

    list->size--;

    Node * oldFirst = list->first;
    list->first = oldFirst->next;
    oldFirst = NULL;

    return 0;

}

/* Removes the last Node from the list.*/
int remove_end(LinkedList *list) {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    if(list->size <= 0)
        return -1;

    list->size--;                    // decrement list size
    //Node * oldLast = list->last;     // get ref to old last
    //oldLast = NULL;                  // set it null
    //free(oldLast);
    Node * startNode = list->first;
    list->last = NULL;               // set listref last to null

    //find the now new last node..
   Node * newLast = NULL;
   while(startNode->next != NULL) {
        newLast=startNode;
   }

    // if list is not empty now..
    if(list->size > 0)
        list->last = newLast;

    return 0;

}

/* Given a List prints all key/string pairs contained in the list to
the screen*/
int print_list(LinkedList *list) {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);


    if(list->size <=0)
        return -1;

    printf("List.size = %d \n", list->size);

    Node *startN = list->first;  //get first

    printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",list->first->key, list->first->string, list->first->next->key);

    //iterate through list
    while(startN->next != NULL) {
        printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",startN->key, startN->string, startN->next->key);
        startN = startN->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Given a List, frees all memory associated with this list. */
void free_list(LinkedList *list) {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    if(list != NULL)
        free(list);
}

/* Given a List and a key, iterates through the whole List and returns
the string of the first node which contains the key */
char * get_string(LinkedList *list, int key) {

    if(DEBUG)
        printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

     Node *startN = list->first;  //get first

    //iterate through list
    while(startN->next != NULL) {
        if(startN->key == key)
            return startN->string;
        else
            startN = startN->next;
    }

    return NULL;

}

/*************** MAIN **************/
int main(void)
{

    LinkedList list = init_list();

    insert_beginning(&list, 1,"im the first" );
    insert_beginning(&list, 2,"im the second" );
    insert_beginning(&list, 3,"im the third" );
    //insert_end(&list, 2, "im the second");
    //insert_end(&list, 3,"im the third");
    //insert_end(&list, 4, "forth here");
    //insert_end(&list, 5, "...and i am last");
    //insert_end(&list, 6, "END");

    print_list(&list);

   // remove_end(&list);
   // remove_beginning(&list);

   // print_list(&list);

   // free_list(&list);

}
```

and here is the output, which is not as expected (but the code compiles just fine):

```
new Node at beginning: '1' 'im the first' '00000000' 
new Node at beginning: '2' 'im the second' '00762EF8' 
new Node at beginning: '3' 'im the third' '00764330' 
List.size = 3 
Node#3.string = 'im the third', .next = '2' 
Node#3.string = 'im the third', .next = '2' 
Node#2.string = 'im the second', .next = '1'
```

As you can see `print_list` either doesn't print the list correctly, or the list itself isn't correct.

- Where have I failed?

As always, Best-Practice hints are very welcome and the source is Public Domain.

Comment: Btw, you may consider to use circular double-linked list, which makes things simplier. Here is an example: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy

Comment: thanks @0andriy, but it was intentional to implement a singly-linkedList instead of a bidirectional one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've weeded out the errors/flaws. Thanks for the advices, it helped me a lot to get this working. I had logic-flaws in `int remove_end(LinkedList *list)` aswell as in `print_list` (thanks to you guys for pointing out!)

..here the whole (working and tested(hopefully clean)) Implementation:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/********** GLOBALS *******************************/
#define OK 0
#define ERROR -1

/********** STRUCT AND TYPES DEFINTIONS ***********/
/* a node with key, data and reference to next node*/
typedef struct Node {
    int key;
    char string[1024];
    struct Node *next;  // pointer to next node
} Node;

/* the actual linked list: ref to first and last Node, size attribute */
typedef struct LinkedList {
    struct Node *first;
    struct Node *last;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

/********** FUNCTION HEADERS **********************/
LinkedList* init_list();
void insert_end(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]);
void insert_beginning(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]);
int remove_end(LinkedList *list);
int remove_beginning(LinkedList *list);
int print_list(LinkedList *list);
void free_list(LinkedList *list);
char * get_string(LinkedList *list, int key);

/*********** FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ***************/

/**
 * init_list Returns an appropriately (for an empty list) initialized struct List
 *
 * @return LinkedList *         ..ptr to the newly initialized list
 */
LinkedList * init_list() {
    printf("initializing list...\n");

    LinkedList *list = (LinkedList*) malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    list->first = NULL;
    list->last = NULL;
    list->size = 0;

    return list;
}

/**
 * Given a List, a key and a string adds a Node containing this
 * information at the end of the list
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *    ..ptr to LinkedList
 * @param key       int             .. key of the Node to be inserted
 * @param string    char[]          .. the string of the Node to be inserted
 */
void insert_end(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    list->size++;                    // increment size of list

    // intialize the new Node
    Node* newN = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newN->key = key;
    strcpy(newN->string, string);
    newN->next = NULL;

    Node* oldLast = list->last;      // get the old last
    oldLast->next = newN;          // make new Node the next Node for oldlast
    list->last = newN;              // set the new last  in the list

    printf("new Node(%p) at end: %d '%s' %p \n", newN, newN->key, newN->string,newN->next);
}

/**
 * Given a List, a key and a string adds a Node, containing
 * this information at the beginning of the list
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *    ..ptr to LinkedList
 * @param key       int             .. key of the Node to be inserted
 * @param string    char[]          .. the string of the Node to be inserted
 */
void insert_beginning(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    list->size++;                    // increment size of list
    Node* oldFirst = list->first;    //get the old first node

    /* intialize the new Node */
    Node* newN = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newN->key = key;
    strcpy(newN->string, string);
    newN->next = oldFirst;

    list->first = newN;              // set the new first

    /* special case: if list size == 1, then this new one is also the last one */
    if (list->size == 1)
        list->last = newN;

    printf("new Node(%p) at beginning: %d '%s' %p \n", newN, newN->key,newN->string, newN->next);
}

/**
 * Removes the first Node from the list
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        .. ptr to the List
 *
 * @return OK | ERROR
 */
int remove_beginning(LinkedList *list) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    if (list->size <= 0)
        return ERROR;

    list->size--;

    Node * oldFirst = list->first;

    printf("delete Node(%p) at beginning: '%d' '%s' '%p' \n", oldFirst,oldFirst->key, oldFirst->string, oldFirst->next);

    free(list->first);          //free it
    list->first = oldFirst->next;
    oldFirst = NULL;

    return OK;
}

/**
 * Removes the last Node from the list.
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        .. ptr to the List
 *
 * @return OK | ERROR
 */
int remove_end(LinkedList *list) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    /* special case #1 */
    if (list->size <= 0)
        return ERROR;

    /* special case #2 */
    if (list->size == 1) {
        free(list->first);
        list->first = NULL;
        list->last = NULL;
        return OK;
    }

    printf("delete Node(%p) at end: '%d' '%s' '%p' \n", list->last,list->last->key, list->last->string, list->last->next);

    list->size--;           // decrement list size
    Node * startNode = list->first;

    /* find the new last node (the one before the old last one); list->size >= 2 at this point!*/
    Node * newLast = startNode;
    while (newLast->next->next != NULL) {
        newLast = newLast->next;
    }

    free(newLast->next);    //free it
    newLast->next = NULL;   //set to NULL to denote new end of list
    list->last = newLast;   // set the new list->last

    return OK;
}

/**
 * Given a List prints all key/string pairs contained in the list to
 * the screen
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        .. ptr to the List
 *
 * @return  OK | ERROR
 */
int print_list(LinkedList *list) {

    printf("----------------------\n");

    if (list->size <= 0)
        return ERROR;

    printf("List.size = %d \n", list->size);

    Node *startN = list->first;  //get first

    /* iterate through list and print contents */
    do {
        printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%p' \n", startN->key,startN->string, startN->next);
        startN = startN->next;
    } while (startN != NULL);

    return OK;
}

/**
 * Given a List, frees all memory associated with this list.
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        ..ptr to the list
 */
void free_list(LinkedList *list) {
    printf("----------------------\n");
    printf("freeing list...\n");

    if (list != NULL && list->size > 0) {
        Node * startN = list->first;
        Node * temp = list->first;

        do {
            free(temp);
            startN = startN->next;
            temp = startN;
        } while (startN != NULL);

        free(list);
    }
}

/**
 * Given a List and a key, iterates through the whole List and returns
 * the string of the first node which contains the key
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        ..ptr to the list
 * @param key       int                 .. the key of the Node to get the String from
 *
 * @return OK | ERROR
 */
char * get_string(LinkedList *list, int key) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    Node *startN = list->first;  //get first

     /* if only one node.. */
     if(list->size == 1)
         return startN->string;

    /* iterate through list and find Node where node->key == key */
    while (startN->next != NULL) {
        if (startN->key == key)
            return startN->string;
        else
            startN = startN->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

/*************** MAIN **************/
int main(void) {

    LinkedList *list = init_list();

    insert_beginning(list, 1, "im the first");
    insert_end(list, 2, "im the second");
    insert_end(list, 3, "im the third");
    insert_end(list, 4, "forth here");

    print_list(list);
    remove_end(list);
    print_list(list);
    remove_beginning(list);
    print_list(list);
    remove_end(list);
    print_list(list);
    printf("string at node with key %d = '%s' \n",2,get_string(list, 2));
    free_list(list);

    return OK;
}
```

Output:

```
initializing list...
----------------------
new Node(00C31668) at beginning: 1 'im the first' 00000000 
----------------------
new Node(00C33E88) at end: 2 'im the second' 00000000 
----------------------
new Node(00C34298) at end: 3 'im the third' 00000000 
----------------------
new Node(00C346A8) at end: 4 'forth here' 00000000 
----------------------
List.size = 4 
Node#1.string = 'im the first', .next = '00C33E88' 
Node#2.string = 'im the second', .next = '00C34298' 
Node#3.string = 'im the third', .next = '00C346A8' 
Node#4.string = 'forth here', .next = '00000000' 
----------------------
delete Node(00C346A8) at end: '4' 'forth here' '00000000' 
----------------------
List.size = 3 
Node#1.string = 'im the first', .next = '00C33E88' 
Node#2.string = 'im the second', .next = '00C34298' 
Node#3.string = 'im the third', .next = '00000000' 
----------------------
delete Node(00C31668) at beginning: '1' 'im the first' '00C33E88' 
----------------------
List.size = 2 
Node#2.string = 'im the second', .next = '00C34298' 
Node#3.string = 'im the third', .next = '00000000' 
----------------------
delete Node(00C34298) at end: '3' 'im the third' '00000000' 
----------------------
List.size = 1 
Node#2.string = 'im the second', .next = '00000000' 
----------------------
string at node with key 2 = 'im the second' 
----------------------
freeing list...
```

Comment: The code got reviewed on Codereview.stackexchange.com: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/164088/132855

Answer (score 1):

Your queue is really a stack as you're pushing things onto the head First in last out order.

I just changed your print_list function as follows;

```
//iterate through list
do {
    printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%p' \n",startN->key, startN->string, startN->next);
    startN = startN->next;
}while(startN != NULL);
```

The output I'm getting with this change is;

```
new Node at beginning: '1' 'im the first' '0x0'
new Node at beginning: '2' 'im the second' '0x2003ac40'
new Node at beginning: '3' 'im the third' '0x2004b088'
List.size = 3
Node#3.string = 'im the third', .next = '0x2004b088'
Node#2.string = 'im the second', .next = '0x2003ac40'
Node#1.string = 'im the first', .next = '0x0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you print the first element twice.

Here:

```
Node *startN = list->first;

printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",list->first->key, list->first->string, list->first->next->key);
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                           //   Same as startN->key !    
//iterate through list
while(startN->next != NULL) {
    printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",startN->key, startN->string, startN->next->key);
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                              //    So in first loop you print the same again.

    startN = startN->next;
}
```

I guess your second `printf` should be:

```
    printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",startN->next->key, startN->next->string, startN->next->key);
                                                           ^^^^^^              ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the print_list function as follows to get an expected result

```
int print_list(LinkedList *list) {

if(DEBUG)
    printf("%s:%d called \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);


if(list->size <=0)
    return -1;

printf("List.size = %d \n", list->size);

Node *startN = list->first;  //get first

// This line is not needed because linked list getting traversed in while loop only 
//printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",list->first->key, list->first->string, list->first->next->key);

//iterate through list
// Here use startN != NULL because last node should also be retrieved.
/* while(startN->next != NULL) {
    printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",startN->key, startN->string, startN->next->key);
    startN = startN->next;
}*/

while(startN != NULL) {
    printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%d' \n",startN->key, startN->string, startN->next->key);
    startN = startN->next;
 }

return 0;}
```